# frozen meat and pork kept in freezer for 4 years never opened

Tags: frozen, ground-beef

I recieved a freezer full of frozen meat is beef or pork is still good if frozen for 4 years. never unfrozen still in package
from store

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It is my understanding that frozen foods may become unappetizing, but because microbes can't multiply in frozen foods they won't become dangerous. (4 years is pretty long, though; are you sure they never melted?)

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to eat but it's all going to be flavorless from freezer burn, most likely. Freezing periods for beef and pork are about 4-5 months, ground meat 2-3 months, and poultry about 6-8 months.